# JSON API not retrieving through fetch due to origin Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB)

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

I continuously keep getting the (settings.js:76 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response) error. I am using the fetch method to retrieve the JSON data from the API, here's my code:

```
 function workUpdate() {
     let data = new FormData();
     let miles = $("radius").value / 1000;
     let zip = "";
     let cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
      for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          let key = cookies[i].split("=");
          if (key[0].trim() == "zip") {
               zip = key[1];
          }
      }
      if (zip == "") {
          $("radius-error").innerHTML = "Please provide your zip code in the personal information tab."
      } else {
          let url = "https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/TrAEIfdiFRU4FNxY94su2FXgrXbCRud9mnfyWdubJSKM5Py7x0g5LjTTd46NXIo8/radius.json/" + zip + "/" + miles + "/mile";
            fetch(url, {mode:'no-cors'})
               .then(checkStatus)
               .then(JSON.parse)
               .then(handleWorkResponse)
               .catch(console.log);
      }
     
 }

function handleWorkResponse(response) {
     let locations = response[0]["zip_code"] + "-";
     for (let i = 1; i < response.length; i++) {
         locations += "-" + response[i]["zip_code"];
     }
     let data = new FormData();
     data.append("locations", locations);
     let url = "php/workupdate.php";
     fetch(url, {method: "POST", body: data, mode:'cors', credentials:'include'})
               .then(checkStatus)
               .then(function() {
                   location.reload();
               })
               .catch(console.log);
 }
```

Comment: [Did you read up on what CORB is and what kinds of requests trigger it?](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md)

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is something the server returns on the response, not something the client adds to the request.

Comment: Yes, i have read about it however i am new to this and I have seen solutions to this using the string 'jsonp' however I dont know how to approach the problem when using the fetch method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE:

As KevinB rightly observed in the comments to this answer, this is a 3rd party API. Hence, changing headers on the server is not possible. To get around this issue, one possible solution is to move this request to your own backend (i.e. hide it behind a request to your own server). Since the same-origin policy does not apply to server-to-server requests, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header does not need to be set when making the request from your server. And since your website will be making the request to your backend, which is the same origin, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header does not need to be set here either.

#### The Fix

Like others mentioned, this a server-side issue. To solve this, set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your server's response object for the given route.

If your server is created with Express, you may do this by adding `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` to the route. `*` here allows for requests from any URL. For more security, you can replace `*` with the URL of the website from which you are fetching from the API.

#### What Is It Though?

It is a security feature used by browsers to minimize the chance of cross-site scripting. For more information on it, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important).

Comment: The server is not created with express. What do you mean by 'set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your server's response object for the given route'?

Comment: @MaksimVengrovski On your server, where you write the router to handle the `"php/workupdate.php"` path, you need to add a header to the HTTP response that the server returns to the client whose key is `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` and whose value is either `"*"` or the URL of your website. A header is metadata attached to the HTTP response sent back to the client; this one in particular tells the browser that this client is authorized by the API to make requests to it.

Comment: @MaksimVengrovski It is a security feature used by browsers to minimize the chance of cross-site scripting. For more information on it, google "same origin policy"

Comment: @ColinMichaelFlaherty the target server is a 3rd party server. Suggesting that the OP add headers to it is misleading at best.

Comment: @KevinB What are you suggesting to do?

Comment: @MaksimVengrovski There's not really much you *can* do. If the api isn't setup to allow requests in the form you're making them, you either cant make them, or need to find some alternative way of making them (such as from your server instead of the browser)

Comment: @KevinB ah, didn't realize that was a 3rd party API since there was no mention

Comment: @ColinMichaelFlaherty This is the solution I was looking for, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the reference of the following website for the api https://www.zipcodeapi.com, what you need to do simply to Set up Client-Side Access and then you are good to go. after creating account go to App Management, click on client side access Setup after that add your domain from where you are requesting.
note: if you are testing from localhost just type: **localhost** in the Website Domain Name(s) *

> This is a CORS related issue. To protect your API key from unauthorized use, you shouldn’t use it in javascript. Instead, you should go to https://www.zipcodeapi.com/ClientKeySetup and set up a client key and use that in the URL. The client key will look like js-XXXXXX.

use your client key:
let url = `"https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/<js-your client key>/radius.json/" + zip + "/" + miles + "/mile";`

sample code:

```
const calculateDistance = async (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault();

          axios.get('https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/js-0ir7ZAGOD9sL2aQr5D1l77MjHL57EEICJWkGoSVilUKsO17zicasBVfvOjt443280S4xcY/distance.json/99501/99950/mile')
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response); 
    
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
           
          });
    
 
      
      };
```